# GIT event API to build an application

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitlab, github-api

Is there any GIT event API, which can be used to detect git events being fired from a system and used to build an application for tracking GIT events such as commit, push, pull, etc.

Comment: @GhostCat - Asking if a particular piece of software (git) exposes a particular API (events as described by OP) is not asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial, or other off-site resource.  Most questions asked here are about things that are documented (if you know where to look).

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger And it turns out - the answer coming in contains a **link** to the github developer pages. What I expected ... and what many people say is a clear indication of a problematic question (when the only good answers are about some external resource ... things are going wrong).

Comment: @GhostCat - Then come up with an *accurate* complaint about the question. Whether someone felt an off-site resource was the best *answer* to the question or not, doesn't change the fact the the question didn't *ask* for an off-site resource.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Fair enough. The question is A) unclear (git or github?) B) pretty broad and C) lacking **any** signs of prior research.

Answer (score 1):

You will need hooks and notification to serve above purpose,

For basic updates like comment and issues related to the repository you'll need Notifications:
https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/notifications/#notification-reasons

For code related updates, Like commit , Pull request you'll need to create hooks:
https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/

Comment: I generally agree that *given the tags* this answers the mostly-likely-intended question.  I think it's important to point out that OP seems to have fallen into the (too common) trap of thinking GitHub and Git are one thing - and they are not.  The closest thing to a "git event API" is git hooks